# Codeigniter : i need to remove id from my url and need to show the name of that event

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-url

I have an url like this

> www.domain.com/controller/functionName/event_id

but i need to do this like:

> www.domain.com/controller/functionName/event_name

I need to show event name in place of ID i need to show event name but i want event id in next page so that i can proceed with and can show right event detail.

i am new in Codeigniter  Can someone explain in simple manner how to pass these parameters to the web server while id is hidden in the url ?

I found some solution for this but i am not able to implement that...Kindly help me for this

Answer (score 2):

```
function name($event_name) {

  $event_id =  $this->model_name->getEventByName($event_name);

  ....

}
```

in the model, the query should be something like

```
SELECT event_id FROM events WHERE name = '$event_name';
```

With the proper escaping of the parameter.

Comment: no my point is that can i pass one more parameter with this that will be hidden event id

Comment: You can pass as many parameters as you want: example.com/controller/method/name/id - and the function - function method($name, $id)

Comment: but i don't want to show id part in my url...then how to do this

Comment: Well, if you don't want it in the url... the only option I see is the one in my answer...

Comment: Use a post value if you don't want it in your URL